Zero-point connected correlator $\langle 1 \rangle_C$ is not 1?
This is so confusing: books are saying that connected correlator is given by
$$\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) ... \phi(x_n) \rangle_C = \left.(-i)^{n-1}\frac{\delta }{\delta J(x_1)} \frac{\delta}{\delta J(x_2)}... \frac{\delta W}{\delta J(x_n)}\right|_{J=0} \tag{1}$$
evaluated at source $J=0$ but for $n=0$ point function I am getting
$$\langle 1 \rangle_C=iW[J=0]= \log(Z[J=0])\tag{2}$$
(by definition of cumulant generating functional $W$). For $n>0$ I get only connected diagrams (as expected).

Is this formula valid only for $n>0$ for some reason?

Also, usually by normalization $Z[J=0]$ is set to $1$ but if I actually evaluate it I get divergent sum of bubble diagrams. Why the discrepancy?



See https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys851/Luty/notes/diagrams.pdf equation (3.18) for example

Ah. I see, $Z[J=0]$ includes all (connected+disconnected) diagrams but when we take the log we get rid of the disconnected ones. And the normalization get rids of the bubble diagrams. Is this correct?

@Nairit_Sahoo To my knowledge


OP is right: The graphical interpretation of OP's eq. (1)
$$ \langle F[\phi]\rangle^c_J~=~F\left[ \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\delta}{\delta J} \right]\frac{i}{\hbar} W_c[J]~=~F\left[ \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\delta}{\delta J} \right]\ln Z[J]\tag{1}$$
is somewhat weird for a connected $0$-point function
$$\langle 1\rangle^c_J~=~\frac{i}{\hbar} W_c[J]~=~\ln Z[J].\tag{2} $$
The connected $0$-point function (2) contains all connected diagrams, cf. OP's title question.
The standard normalization of eq. (2) is
$$\begin{align}   Z_{g=0}[J\!=\!0]~=~&1,\cr 
\langle 1\rangle^c_{g=0,J=0}~=~\frac{i}{\hbar} W^c_{g=0}[J\!=\!0]~=~\ln Z_{g=0}[J\!=\!0]~=~&0.\end{align}\tag{3} $$
The connected $0$-point function (2) should be compared to the definition of a (not necessarily connected) $0$-point function
$$\langle 1\rangle_J~\equiv~\frac{Z[J]}{Z[J]}~\equiv~1.\tag{4}$$

Concerning the normalization of $Z_{g=0}[J\!=\!0]$, see footnote 1 in my Phys.SE answer here.



Qmechanic: what about composite operators? (E.g., what if the source was a mass term, rather than a simple linear current?)

Hi @TLDR: 1. $J$s are here for simplicity assumed to be external sources for non-composite fields $\phi$ only. 2. A mass term $m$ in the interaction part are viewed as a 2-vertex coupling $g$. However, the generalization to sources for composite fields is in principle straightforward.
